# Azure Resource Graph Explorer KQL multi-level JSON nesting

Tags: kql, azure-resource-graph

I'm working on a query using my miserable skills with KQL.
The problem I am having is extracting data from multiple nested JSONs.

As an example, When I check the output of this query:

```
securityresources | where type =~ "microsoft.security/assessments/subassessments"
        | extend assessmentKey=extract(@"(?i)providers/Microsoft.Security/assessments/([^/]*)", 1, id), subAssessmentId=tostring(properties.id), parentResourceId= extract("(.+)/providers/Microsoft.Security", 1, id)
        | extend resourceId = tostring(properties.resourceDetails.id)
        | extend subAssessmentName=tostring(properties.displayName),
            subAssessmentDescription=tostring(properties.description),
            subAssessmentRemediation=tostring(properties.remediation),
            subAssessmentCategory=tostring(properties.category),
            subAssessmentImpact=tostring(properties.impact),
            severity=tostring(properties.status.severity),
            status=tostring(properties.status.code),
            cause=tostring(properties.status.cause),
            statusDescription=tostring(properties.status.description),
            additionalData=tostring(properties.additionalData)
        | where assessmentKey == "xxx"
                      | where status == "Unhealthy"
        | summarize numOfResources=dcount(resourceId), timeGenerated=arg_max(todatetime(properties.timeGenerated), additionalData) by assessmentKey, subAssessmentId, subAssessmentName, subAssessmentCategory, severity, status, cause, statusDescription, subAssessmentDescription, subAssessmentRemediation, subAssessmentImpact
        | extend high = iff(severity == "High", 3,0), medium = iff(severity == "Medium", 2, 0), low = iff(severity == "Low", 1 ,0)
        | extend all = high + medium + low
        | extend additionalData = parse_json(additionalData)
        | extend data = parse_json(additionalData.data)
        | extend vendorReferences = parse_json(data.VendorReferences) 
        | extend imageDetails = parse_json(data.ImageDetails)
        | extend containers = parse_json(data.Containers)
        | extend imageId = parse_json(data.ImageId)
        | extend cvss = parse_json(data.Cvss)
        | extend cve = parse_json(data.Cve)
        | project cvss
```

I will get the following result:

```
{
    "2.0": {
        "$type": "additionalData/cvss",
        "cvssVectorString": "CVSS:2.0/AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:C/E:POC/RL:OF/RC:C",
        "base": 7.8
    },
    "3.0": {
        "$type": "additionalData/cvss",
        "cvssVectorString": "CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H/E:P/RL:O/RC:C",
        "base": 7.5
    }
}
```

And from that I would like to project into two colums, which should look like something like this:

- CVSS 2.0 Base: 7.8
- CVSS 3.1 Base: 7.5

To make matters worse, an even more complex scenario would be to substract info from containers. If right now I would use

```
project containers
```

Then the end result would be something like this:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "cont-name",
        "Pod": {
            "Name": "pod-name-1",
            "Namespace": "namespace-staging",
            "ControllerName": "controller-name",
            "ControllerType": "ReplicaSet"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "cont-name",
        "Pod": {
            "Name": "pod-name-2",
            "Namespace": "namespace-staging",
            "ControllerName": "controller-name",
            "ControllerType": "ReplicaSet"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "cont-name",
        "Pod": {
            "Name": "pod-name-3",
            "Namespace": "namespace-staging",
            "ControllerName": "controller-name",
            "ControllerType": "ReplicaSet"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "cont-name",
        "Pod": {
            "Name": "pod-name-4",
            "Namespace": "namespace-prod",
            "ControllerName": "controller-name",
            "ControllerType": "ReplicaSet"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "cont-name",
        "Pod": {
            "Name": "pod-name-5",
            "Namespace": "namespace-prod",
            "ControllerName": "controller-name",
            "ControllerType": "ReplicaSet"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "cont-name",
        "Pod": {
            "Name": "pod-name-6",
            "Namespace": "namespace-prod",
            "ControllerName": "controller-name",
            "ControllerType": "ReplicaSet"
        }
    }
]
```

And from the above I need to extract the container name and, ideally, the namespace though I can image this might not be possible. So just the container nanme.

Unfortunately this is far beyond my skills and I have no clue where to even begin with.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

W.

I tried something like this:

```
| extend cvss20base = cvss["2.0"]["base"]
```

but the results are always null.

I could not come up with any other options

#########################################

Ok, I'll try to explain this in a bit more detail.
Let's say my query looks (ends) like this, and let's make this the baseline to work on:

```
        | extend additionalData = parse_json(additionalData)
        | extend data = parse_json (additionalData.data)
        | project data
```

If I run the query, this is the output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJRWn.png)

If we get into more details, we get this:

[Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU2DM.png)

73 rows are returned. And the Data contains all the info I need.

Based on that, I can project for:

- Type
- InventorySource
- PublishedTime
  etc.
  Basically, anywhere where I don't have yet another JSON nested.

But what I need to further extract are certain values from, let's say, Cvss, which is a JSON. I can further add something like this:

```
        | extend cvss = parse_json (data.Cvss)
        | project cvss
```

And as a result I get 73 results that look like this:
[cvss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvrXw.png)

Each of those rows, after prettifying, looks like that:

```
{
    "2.0": {
        "$type": "additionalData/cvss",
        "cvssVectorString": "CVSS:2.0/AV:A/AC:M/Au:M/C:N/I:C/A:P/E:U/RL:OF/RC:C",
        "base": 5.4
    },
    "3.0": {
        "$type": "additionalData/cvss",
        "cvssVectorString": "CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:L/UI:R/S:U/C:L/I:N/A:N/E:U/RL:O/RC:C",
        "base": 3.5
    }
}
```

And finally from that I need to extract the cvss base value for 2.0 and 3.0.

I tried playing around with mv-expand, more JSON parsing like

```
        | extend cvss20 = parse_json(cvss.[0])
        | project cvss20
```

But whatever option I try I always get null results :(

I hope this is all clear now.

#########################################

Ok, finally getting somewhere!

```
        | extend additionalData = parse_json(additionalData)
        | extend data = parse_json (additionalData.data)
        | extend cvss = parse_json (data.Cvss)
        | extend cvss_ext = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(cvss)))
        | extend x = cvss_ext.["2.0"]
        | extend y = cvss_ext.["3.0"]
        | extend cvss20 = x.base
        | extend cvss30 = y.base
        | project cvss20, cvss30
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKyS1.png)

Wish me luck :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use below **`KQL queries`** to get desired result:

**`1st KQL query to get CVSS and Base:`**

```
let rithTable1 = datatable(JCol: dynamic) [dynamic({
    "2.0": {
        "$type": "additionalData/cvss",
        "cvssVectorString": "CVSS:2.0/AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:N/I:N/A:C/E:POC/RL:OF/RC:C",
        "base": 7.8
    },
    "3.0": {
        "$type": "additionalData/cvss",
        "cvssVectorString": "CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:H/E:P/RL:O/RC:C",
        "base": 7.5
    }
})];
rithTable1
| mv-expand JCol
| project x = split(JCol,":")
| project y = split(x[4],'/'), z = split(x[-1],'}')
| project CVSS =y [0], Base = z[0]
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[Fiddle.](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA62RUU%20DMBDH3/kUl8aEkTA6nEZTswesGjWLW8DxQnjogCiGAYG6wCbf3SsYx4tvtmly97/r9df8s0RClcr3V7HNEhsWEAuJG5PJMy8yBnGbi10aGRD8RJOjBrjIuTUjDIakF85kWyYoERHHqUyLXGR3OIpG%207om5qlP5X4SyaLyZJXmb%20oK9z2P4UTq%20OyFOpwtqfOJEcfzpBTG6T1brzh1l2z1QF3O%20HjmVtTq6Svrute6oUTm/844t%20wR49rFaKMAPbYZwT4q2B71b9LLgVTrjPBGO1mgfcFuP02aUuQxKAtQKKviA2GgQX/qMktl741JGDFG1fa32gQXoalT3TDhMBKnNqqdPr6j/gSLFoJZaMItomH7AZNvFCP/PBcCAAA=)

**`2nd KQL query`** to get container name and namespace:

```
let rithTable2 = datatable(JCol: dynamic) [dynamic([
{
        "Name": "cont-name",
        "Pod": {
            "Name": "pod-name-1",
            "Namespace": "namespace-staging",
            "ControllerName": "controller-name",
            "ControllerType": "ReplicaSet"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "cont-name",
        "Pod": {
            "Name": "pod-name-2",
            "Namespace": "namespace-staging",
            "ControllerName": "controller-name",
            "ControllerType": "ReplicaSet"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "cont-name",
        "Pod": {
            "Name": "pod-name-3",
            "Namespace": "namespace-staging",
            "ControllerName": "controller-name",
            "ControllerType": "ReplicaSet"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "cont-name",
        "Pod": {
            "Name": "pod-name-4",
            "Namespace": "namespace-prod",
            "ControllerName": "controller-name",
            "ControllerType": "ReplicaSet"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "cont-name",
        "Pod": {
            "Name": "pod-name-5",
            "Namespace": "namespace-prod",
            "ControllerName": "controller-name",
            "ControllerType": "ReplicaSet"
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "cont-name",
        "Pod": {
            "Name": "pod-name-6",
            "Namespace": "namespace-prod",
            "ControllerName": "controller-name",
            "ControllerType": "ReplicaSet"
        }
    }])];
rithTable2
| mv-expand JCol
| project  Container_Name=JCol.Name, Pod_Name = JCol.Pod.Name, Pod_Namespace = JCol.Pod.Namespace
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[Fiddle.](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA%20VVO2/CMBDeI%20U/nDKBRJBKHwOIiY0BVS0bQtXVPoGRY1vGqopa/nvPJi1pWDp0qBpnufsezn1eTlMAr8J2ic%20aRjAFiYE/bnrzmdVjkAeDlRJ9WNVVb5Vnb3kG9SkWWFExhkJYE0oTm0GDvbeSyYb%20m8dZmSzlVdP0Jdk7FElnPptyH3CjzOZCPuO/e6s1%20eY8J%20RiqpZjeXDJ8UBOK4GPFIqz9ngqj7X915OPOpv8urPJb36a3Hm%208N/Evu1m7Lu/HXvdX0/y7LwD8uwdqpeSXh0aCXEJRIRn25EIAPF2VIb8U5xnGvlhrAbAz5EwXiIJ5b7FpJhtOoEfPpFeYIcGAAA=)

Comment: Thank you for the input, however this is not exactly what I'm after. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough, my bad.

Comment: To start from the beginning, the query I posted is a slightly modified version of a built-in query available fro Microsoft Defender for Cloud. This query shows all vulnerabilities in Kubernetes clusters. I need to run this query, export it to csv and send this to my Client.

The majority of data which is of value to me is in the additionalData section. The problem I am having is that this data is multi-layered, so I can't just project it and export to CSV and send it off to the Client because it will be unreadable.

Comment: That's why I need a way to extract all the needed information from different layers, project it in the same output and then send off to the Client.

Comment: if data is in different tables, then you can use join operator for it, To be honest you have mentioned that you want output and gave input,for that i have answered

Comment: Please see my edit in the original post. Hopefully it will make more sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with something that somewhat satisfies me:

```
securityresources | where type =~ "microsoft.security/assessments/subassessments"
        | extend assessmentKey=extract(@"(?i)providers/Microsoft.Security/assessments/([^/]*)", 1, id), subAssessmentId=tostring(properties.id), parentResourceId= extract("(.+)/providers/Microsoft.Security", 1, id)
        | extend resourceId = tostring(properties.resourceDetails.id)
        | extend subAssessmentName=tostring(properties.displayName),
            subAssessmentDescription=tostring(properties.description),
            subAssessmentRemediation=tostring(properties.remediation),
            subAssessmentCategory=tostring(properties.category),
            subAssessmentImpact=tostring(properties.impact),
            severity=tostring(properties.status.severity),
            status=tostring(properties.status.code),
            cause=tostring(properties.status.cause),
            statusDescription=tostring(properties.status.description),
            additionalData=tostring(properties.additionalData)
        | where assessmentKey == "xxx"
                      | where status == "Unhealthy"
        | summarize numOfResources=dcount(resourceId), timeGenerated=arg_max(todatetime(properties.timeGenerated), additionalData) by assessmentKey, subAssessmentId, subAssessmentName, subAssessmentCategory, severity, status, cause, statusDescription, subAssessmentDescription, subAssessmentRemediation, subAssessmentImpact
        | extend high = iff(severity == "High", 3,0), medium = iff(severity == "Medium", 2, 0), low = iff(severity == "Low", 1 ,0)
        | extend all = high + medium + low
        | extend additionalData = parse_json(additionalData)
        | extend data = parse_json (additionalData.data)
        | extend cvss = parse_json (data.Cvss)
        | extend cvss_ext = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(cvss)))
        | extend cvss_20_base = cvss_ext.["2.0"].base
        | extend cvss_30_base = cvss_ext.["3.0"].base
        | extend vr = parse_json(data.VendorReferences)
        | extend vr_ext = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(vr)))
        | extend Vendor_reference_id = vr_ext[0].Id
        | extend Vendor_reference_url = vr_ext[0].Url
        | extend img = parse_json(data.ImageDetails)
        | extend img_ext = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(img)))
        | extend image = img_ext.OSDetails
        | extend cve = parse_json(data.Cve)
        | extend cve_ext = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(cve)))
        | extend cve_number = cve_ext[0].Id
        | extend cve_url = cve_ext[0].Url
        | extend containers = parse_json(data.Containers)
        | extend containers_ext = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(containers)))
        | extend container_name = containers_ext[0].Name 
        | project   Type = data.Type, 
                    VendorReferenceID = Vendor_reference_id, 
                    VendorReferenceUrl = Vendor_reference_url,
                    Container = container_name,
                    Published = data.PublishedTime,
                    Scanned = data.ScanTime,
                    ImageID = data.ImageId,
                    Patchable = data.Patchable,
                    Cvs20Base = cvss_20_base,
                    Cvs30Base = cvss_30_base,
                    Tag = data.Tag,
                    CveId = cve_number,
                    CveUrl = cve_url
```

I still have no idea what I was doing by at least it works.